# How to add Jcombobox in to my java SWT swing window

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How to add this JComboBox into my JAVA SWT WINDOW.

```
 DefaultComboBoxModel<myCombo> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<myCombo>();
 final JComboBox<myCombo> combobox = new JComboBox<myCombo>(comboModel);
```

eg:

I have added a button into my SWT Window.

```
    Button btnNewButton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnNewButton.setBounds(193, 310, 126, 25);
    btnNewButton.setText("Add Quantities");
```

Comment: You are mixing up SWT and Swings. You can use Combo or CCombo widget of SWT instead of JComboBox. Any specific reason why you want to use JComboBox instead of Combo or CCombo?

Comment: I need to add object(it contain two variables) into the list of a combobox.  In CCombobox I cant add objects into it but with JComboBox we can achieve it.

Comment: which of the two members of the object will the combobox displays?

Answer (score 0):

Visit the following website..

**http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingJComboBoxComponents.htm**